# Php script find square root of a given number error

Tags: php

I simple php program that returns the square root of a number, although when I echo the results, I get the following error and I am tired, so Im probably missing something really small here.

Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Task 2</title></head>
<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class square
    {
        public $num=null;
        public $objRes=null;
        function processRequest()
    {

    $this->square=$_REQUEST['num'];
    }

    function run()
{
        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $this->processRequest();
        $this->objRes=sqrt($this->square);

    }   
    }
}
        $objSquare=new square();
        $objSquare->run();




?>
    <form action="task2.php" method="POST">
        Enter the number:<input type="text" name="num"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php

        if($objSquare->res!=0) {
            echo "Square root of a given number is ".$objSquare->objRes." ";
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Heres my error:-

Notice: Undefined property: square::$res in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/task-2/task2.php on line 46

Comment: `if($objSquare->objRes!=0) {`, not `if($objSquare->res!=0) {`

Comment: I would get tired too with code that is indented like this.

Comment: That could probably be the reason why i'm so tired Daan!

Comment: Ok so I tried that, error is gone, but not echoing my result...any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Change `$objSquare->res` to `$objSquare->objRes` because that's the name of your `square` class property.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you asked for. But sometimes people don't know they wanted something until they have it.

#### Example using sqrt()

```
// Precision depends on your precision directive
echo sqrt(9); // 3
echo sqrt(10); // 3.16227766 ...
```